# Find Distance using Latitude/Longitude using Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I have a CSV consisting of **Places of Interest** in one table and Other table consists of **office locations** of a company. Both the tables consist of Latitude and Longitude information as well.

Structure of CSV file consisting of **Places of Interest**

POI_Name   Longitude   Latitude City
POI_1   77.573957   12.970125   Bangalore
POI_2   77.579886   13.009582 Bangalore
POI_3   77.546688   13.023931 Chennai

Similarly we have a CSV file with **office locations** of a company

Office   Longitude   Latitude  City 
Office_1 78.324445   12.970125 Bangalore 
Office_2 77.254555   13.234444 Chennai 
Office_3 76.098438   14.135567 Bangalore

Both tables consists of thousands of records. Now I want to create a query in Neo4J that will give me top 5 **Nearest place of interest** to the **office location** (Passed as a parameter in the query) in the decreasing order at the run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the distance bewteen two nodes every time will be the same, I recommend you parse all places vs all offices and create a "distance" relation with a value of distance in km or whatever between the nodes(placei,officej), then you only query the first n nearest nodes from another node (then you can run a query like: MATCH (p:Place)-[d:DISTANCE]->(o:Office{myoffice}) RETURN p,o,d ORDER BY d.km ASC LIMIT 5). You will save time and computational cost.

Anyway you can use something like the next query:

```
MATCH (p:Place), (o:Office {id:myoffice}) RETURN distance(point({latitude: p.latitude, longitude: p.longitude}), point({latitude: o.latitude, longitude: o.longitude})) / 1000.0 as km, p, o ORDER BY km ASC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks @juanbits for the response. This is what I wanted.